# React Navigation transition between nested stack and tabnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having some problem with React Navigation.

I have a tab navigator with different tabs, one of them being a StackNavigator.
Some times I wan't to navigate from Tab1 to some screen (let say A) in the StackNavigator
I wan't some action to go back to Tab1 from the A screen in the StackNavigator.

I was able to find this action dispatching a. navigate action.

But I'm unable to have a "back" transition  from A to Tab1

Many thanks for your help.

Regards, 
David

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your "Screen A"

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}/>,
    backBehavior: 'initialRoute'
});
```

Don't forget to import `HeaderBackButton`:

`import {HeaderBackButton} from 'react-navigation';`